# docker.service: failed to start and not found

Tags: docker, synology

Im really at the beginning of diving into Linux world and its CLI, so I apologize for my lack of knowledge in this matter.
But what is my problem?

Im trying to install "docker" on my Synology DS418. Following this guide https://wiki.servarr.com/docker-arm-synology everything runs smoothly until I try to check if docker starts via

```
systemctl start docker
```

it reports

```
Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

When I run

```
systemctl status docker
```

it states

```
docker.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

This feels like the installation wasnt properly setup, am I correct? What can I do to start docker and run it correctly?

Comment: Please check you have docker binaries in /usr/local/bin or /usr/bin/

Comment: Yes: /usr/local/bin lists the docker binaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all following readers with the same confusion: actually it seems that the docker.service is not needed in that case. With a lot of research I managed to install "portainer" via ssh in CLI, so docker works. Im kinda proud of myself that I did it all by myself, yay!
Thank you though for the help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).